# SQL include record every nth record in query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
QueryA      QueryB
Col1        Col1
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           d
5           e
...
100
```

I want to take the results of QueryA and for every nth record (let's say every fifth record) I want to take a random record from QueryB and put it into the result of QueryA, so that it looks something like this:

```
CombinedQueryResults
1
2
3
4
5
a
6
7
8
9
10
d
11
12
13
14
15
f
...
```

This is my initial thinking of how to get this working.

1. I have two queries
2. Use Row_Number on both
3. For the first Query, Row number would increase by 1, for the second query it would increase by 4s and adding 0.1 (this way later when it's sorted it will come after).
4. Use NEWGUID() to make the second query random
5. Union the queries and then order by the row number

Is there a better way to do this? I'm not great at SQL and feel like this isn't quite right.

```
DECLARE
    @tblA   TABLE(Col1 INT)

DECLARE
    @tblB   TABLE(Col1 INT)


DECLARE
    @i  INT = 0

WHILE @i < 100
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    INSERT INTO @tblA (Col1)
    VALUES (@i)
END

SET @i = 0;

WHILE @i < 100 * 1000
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1 * 1000
    INSERT INTO @tblB (Col1)
    VALUES (@i)
END


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1 ASC) AS RowNumber, * FROM @tblA
UNION
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID() ASC) * 4 + 0.1) AS RowNumber, *  FROM @tblB
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

***EDIT***
From the answers I'm recieving below, either everyone is using what I already wrote as the example to go based off of or great minds think alike. I'm going to assume that what I wrote is the right direction and go from there. Thanks for confirming what I was thinking.

Comment: Tag your question with the data base you are using.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables have no inherent order.  Let me assume that both `a` and `b` have *another* column that specifies the ordering.

If so, then you can use `row_number()` and some number logic:

```
select col
from ((select a.col, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum, 1 as priority
       from a
      ) union all
      (select b.col, row_number() over (order by newid()) * 5 as seqnum, 2 as priority
       from b
      )
     ) ab
order by seqnum, priority;
```

Comment: I believe yours is basically what I wrote above. I don't believe priority is needed. Also, multiplying by 5 will make it the 6th record, not the 5th. That is why in my example I multiply by 4 and add 0.1. But thanks for trying. Basically it seems like I'm doing it the right way, but it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: @SteveBuchok . . . Your method is fine if it works.  This should also work.  It uses a second `order by` key for the ordering.

Comment: I appreciate you trying, but the second order by key isn't needed. You ended up just making a slightly more complicated version of what I had already done and really didn't answer the underlying question. Is there a better way to do this. And I guess the answer is, no, there isn't a better way to do this. Again, I appreciate you trying. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of CTEs to preprocess the queries and assign a sequence number to each row. Then, a final query can order by this sequence number and show the result you want. For example:

```
with
a as (
  -- your queryA here
),
b as (
  -- your queryB here
),
together as (
  select col1, row_number() over(order by col1) * 1.0 as seq from a
  union all
  select col1, row_number() over(order by col1) * 5.0 + 0.1 from b
)
select col1 from together order by seq
```

Comment: I don't think this is any better or clearer than mine and don't see how it would perform any better. The union is basically exactly like the one I wrote.